# TextBlock Set in a specific Co ordinate inside an image in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, caliburn.micro

I'm stuck in a problem . I can calculate distance from 2 points . And I want to set the TextBlock after I Draw Line . Please not that I don't use any Graphics property to write inside image . I use TextBlock because that is not write inside image . Here is my XAML code ..

```
 <Canvas Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableCanvas}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=ISCanvasVisible, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
                <!--<Canvas Margin="10,10,0,10" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableCanvas}" Background="Gray"  Visibility="{Binding Path=ISCanvasVisible, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"  >-->
                <Image Source="{Binding DIIMG_For_Folder}"    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MDownCalCulateDistance_Right($source, $eventArgs)];
                [Event MouseUp] = [Action MUpCalCulateDistance_Right($source, $eventArgs)];
                [Event MouseMove] = [Action MMoveCalCulateDistance_Right($source, $eventArgs)]" Stretch="Uniform" />
                <Line Visibility="{Binding Path=ISLineDistanceVisible, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"  IsHitTestVisible="False"  X1="{Binding FirstPoint_Right.X}" Y1="{Binding FirstPoint_Right.Y}"
                  X2="{Binding SecondPoint_Right.X}" Y2="{Binding SecondPoint_Right.Y}"
                  Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3">
                </Line>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisTanceInMM_Right, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="15" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red" ></TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
```

As you can See I use  property to connect two point and show the Line. But You also see The TextBlock I set a fixed point that is Margin 15 . I want to set when I draw the line after the secondpoint.x and Secondpoint.Y. Here is my C# code

```cs
            try
            {
                if (_firstPointRight.X == 0 && _firstPointRight.Y == 0)
                {
                    System.Windows.Point px1 = e.GetPosition((System.Windows.Controls.Image)sender);

                    _firstPointRight = px1;
                }
                else
                //if (_secondPointRight.X == 0 && _secondPointRight.Y == 0)
                {
                    System.Windows.Point px2 = e.GetPosition((System.Windows.Controls.Image)sender);
                    _secondPointRight = px2;
                    var geometry = new FrameGeometry(DicomDataSet);
                    var patientCoord1 = geometry.TransformImagePointToPatient(new Point2(Convert.ToInt32(_firstPointRight.X), Convert.ToInt32(_firstPointRight.Y)));
                    var patientCoord2 = geometry.TransformImagePointToPatient(new Point2(Convert.ToInt32(_secondPointRight.X), Convert.ToInt32(_secondPointRight.Y)));
                    double distanceInMM = patientCoord1.Distance(patientCoord2);
                    DisTanceInMM_Right = Convert.ToDouble(distanceInMM.ToString("N3"));
                }
            }
            catch (DicomDataException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Dicom File Not Suported", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
```

The DisTanceInMM_Righ is the property I set the distance between two points and show the distance using TextBlock. I want to set after Secondpoint can it possible . I don't want to use as Margin property or Fixed place TextBlock use. Please Note I use Caliburn.Micro Framework .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you want your TextBlock to appear after second line point. If so you can use `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties on TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding SecondPoint_Right.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding SecondPoint_Right.Y}" Text="{Binding Path=DisTanceInMM_Right, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
```